# Flask, Fetch, Login - Can't return logged user to the rest of site

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, fetch

I have a problem with fetch API at flask app.
I'm trying to log in user using fetch request (I would like to make a site which not visibly reload for user) and inside post request everything works fine, user is logged in in a route which I make request, but if I refresh page then it's gone.

Do you have any ideas why does it happen?

My login route:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    data = request.json
    user = models.User.query.filter_by(email=data.get("email")).first()
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, data.get("password")):
        login_user(user, remember=data.get("remember") == "true")
        redirect_url = url_for('index')
        return jsonify(loggedIn=True, redirectUrl=redirect_url)
    else:
        return jsonify(loggedIn=False, error='Invalid Email/Password')
```

and my fetch api:

```
    let loginUrl = "/login"
    fetch(loginUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: loginEmailField.value,
            password: loginPasswordField.value,
            remember: String(loginRememberField.checked)
        }),
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
    })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
    })
```

When I print current_user.is_authenticated inside of login route then it returns true, but inside of index route after refresh it's false.

Any ideas?